# difference between battery and capacitor in urdu languege

Tags: electrostatics

### Heading

1. List item
2. List item`enter code here`

> Blockquote*emphasized text*

Answer (score 2):

Well, a battery is بیٹری

A capacitor is سندارتر or گنجائشدار - see http://ur.wikipedia.org/wiki/گنجائشدار

They look different to me. ;-)

Comment: Ha ha Lumo, LOL :-D